# Karma launcher: Waiting 15 seconds

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

With the new karma launcher for phantomJS, I am getting an annoying "Waiting 15 seconds" every time I run the tests.

The only page remotely relevant to this problem is here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1545

I've swapped node and karma versions a few times to try to get it to work without success. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Here's the combination of tools I'm using:

> ```
> Node version: v0.10.40
> karma: 0.13.15
> karma-chrome-launcher: 0.2.2
> karma-jasmine: 0.3.6
> karma-phantomjs-launcher: 0.2.1
> ```

```
26 01 2016 15:06:21.897:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.15 server started at http://localhost:9877/karma/
26 01 2016 15:06:21.897:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
26 01 2016 15:06:21.905:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: ACTION REQUIRED:
26 01 2016 15:06:21.905:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: 
26 01 2016 15:06:21.905:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:   Launch browser at
26 01 2016 15:06:21.905:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:   http://localhost:9000/webkit/inspector/inspector.html?page=2
26 01 2016 15:06:21.905:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: 
26 01 2016 15:06:21.906:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: Waiting 15 seconds ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the [karma-phantomjs2-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs2-launcher) and you get the "waiting 15 seconds" message when debug setting is set to true. Flicking it to false got rid of the message in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to use `phantomJS`. People report that its functionality can differ from Chrome or other browsers. Also you need to download it, which may fail to resume on errors.

It is more robust and reliable to use Chrome and any other real browsers you want to support. In fact, it is the **main strength of Karma** that you run your tests in **real browsers**.

[Here is a minimal setup I wrote](https://github.com/dmitriz/min-karma) to get your started quickly, that you can also add to your current project with the single command

```
npm install min-karma -D
```

It uses Chrome but you can add any other supported browser.

It definitely will not let you wait more than a second.